# MySQL : Indexes for View based on an aggregated query

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, view

I have a working, nice, indexed SQL query aggregating notes (sum of ints) for all my users and others stuffs. This is "query A".

I want to use this aggregated notes in others queries, say "query B".

**If I create a View based on "query A", will the indexes of the original query will be used when needed if I join it in "query B" ?**

Is that true for MySQL ? For others flavors of SQL ?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "an indexed SQL query"? You mean it uses options like `FORCE INDEX`?

Comment: Nope, simply a query with multiples joins and conditions, all on indexed columns.

Comment: Simply try it.  Use `EXPLAIN SELECT <<query B>>`.  In general, `VIEWs` are syntactic sugar and provide nothing much else.  Also, what version of MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you cannot create an index on a view. MySQL uses indexes of the underlying tables when you query data against the views that use the merge algorithm. For the views that use the temptable algorithm, indexes are not utilized when you query data against the views.

https://www.percona.com/blog/2007/08/12/mysql-view-as-performance-troublemaker/

Comment: So the merge algorithm would be fine but cannot be used here because of the aggregations in my query A. So no indexes for me. 
Is that Mysql specific ?

Comment: Internallly the view use index to create the aggreagtion. But you can't use index on something like `SELECT * FROM view v JOIN table t ON v.id = t.id`

Comment: So Juan Carlos Oropeza the view is pertinent on very small set of data ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a demo table. It has a `userid` attribute column and a `note` column.

mysql> create table t (id serial primary key, userid int not null, note int, key(userid,note));

If you do an aggregation to get the sum of `note` per `userid`, it does an index-scan on `(userid, note)`.

```
mysql> explain select userid, sum(note) from t group by userid;
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+--------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key    | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+--------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t     | index | userid        | userid | 9       | NULL |    1 | Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+--------+---------+------+------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

If we create a view for the same query, then we can see that querying the view uses the same index on the underlying table. Views in MySQL are pretty much like macros — they just query the underlying table.

```
mysql> create view v as select userid, sum(note) from t group by userid;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> explain select * from v;
+----+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+--------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type  | possible_keys | key    | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+--------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | ALL   | NULL          | NULL   | NULL    | NULL |    2 | NULL        |
|  2 | DERIVED     | t          | index | userid        | userid | 9       | NULL |    1 | Using index |
+----+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+--------+---------+------+------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

So far so good.

Now let's create a table to join with the view, and join to it.

mysql> create table u (userid int primary key, name text);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.09 sec)

```
mysql> explain select * from v join u using (userid);
+----+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+-------------+---------+---------------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type  | possible_keys | key         | key_len | ref           | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+-------------+---------+---------------+------+-------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | u          | ALL   | PRIMARY       | NULL        | NULL    | NULL          |    1 | NULL        |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | ref   | <auto_key0>   | <auto_key0> | 4       | test.u.userid |    2 | NULL        |
|  2 | DERIVED     | t          | index | userid        | userid      | 9       | NULL          |    1 | Using index |
+----+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+-------------+---------+---------------+------+-------------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

I tried to use hints like `straight_join` to force it to read `v` then join to `u`.

```
mysql> explain select * from v straight_join u on (v.userid=u.userid);
+----+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+--------+---------+------+------+----------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type  | possible_keys | key    | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                                              |
+----+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+--------+---------+------+------+----------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | ALL   | NULL          | NULL   | NULL    | NULL |    7 | NULL                                               |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | u          | ALL   | PRIMARY       | NULL   | NULL    | NULL |    1 | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |
|  2 | DERIVED     | t          | index | userid        | userid | 9       | NULL |    7 | Using index                                        |
+----+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+--------+---------+------+------+----------------------------------------------------+
```

"Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)" is MySQL's terminology for "no index used for the join." It's just looping over the table the hard way -- by reading batches of rows from start to finish of the table.

I tried to use `force index` to tell MySQL that `type=ALL` is to be avoided.

```
mysql> explain select * from v straight_join u force index(PRIMARY) on (v.userid=u.userid);
+----+-------------+------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+----------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref      | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+----------+------+-------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | ALL    | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL     |    7 | NULL        |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | u          | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | v.userid |    1 | NULL        |
|  2 | DERIVED     | t          | index  | userid        | userid  | 9       | NULL     |    7 | Using index |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+----------+------+-------------+
```

Maybe this is using an index for the join? But it's weird that table `u` is before table `t` in the EXPLAIN. I'm frankly not sure how to understand what it's doing, given the order of rows in this EXPLAIN report. I would expect the joined table should come *after* the primary table of the query.

I only put a few rows of data into each table. One might get some different EXPLAIN results with a larger representative sample of test data. I'll leave that to you to try.

Comment: Yes, thanks Bill Karwin. I heard everywhere that view (with aggregations) cannot use indexes. It seems to be a fact, so if my view is containing more than hundreds of lines, it's look like  a bad idea.

Comment: To be honest I can't figure a valid use case for views in realworld mysql

Comment: The `sys` schema has a lot of views to simplify complex queries you would have to do yourself to query the performance schema. Also views can be useful to provide limited access to tables the user doesn't normally have access to query.